# viewDidLoad() is called every time after dismiss() of UIImagePickerController()

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I presented `UIImagePickerController()` from `ViewControllerA` and when I select a image its delegate called and in that delegate I wrote

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

but `viewDidLoad()` of `ViewControllerA` also called

Comment: `viewDidLoad` called only once when you enter in ViewController.

Comment: @ivarun: no , it is calling again as soon as i select an image

Comment: how did you get to know that viewDidLoad is getting called? via Breakpoints or log or print messages?

Comment: @hardikparmar: Yes via break points

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: @krishankumar show the rest of your code.. you are messing something in the rest of the code, `viewDidLoad` for a single instance of `UIViewController` is always called just once

Answer (score 1):

Please find below code, viewDidLoad doesn't get called every time.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("View Did Load")
}

private func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);

    _ = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Open Photo Library using this code,

```
@IBAction func btnclicked(_ sender: Any) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    picker.delegate = self
    self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Also post some of your code so I can review it.

Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

When using the UIImagePickerViewController, often times the camera will cause a memory warning and your viewcontroller's viewDidUnload method will be called. Next time your view is shown (when the UIImagePickerViewController is dismissed), the viewDidLoad method will be called because it was previously unloaded.

Comment: You can recreate anything that was removed in viewDidUnload, or you can check to see if it is already created in viewDidLoad, and not do it again.

Comment: i have a tableView which i populate on viewDidLoad() , so due to this api called twice and in another project written in Objective-C same is not happening

Comment: what if i use PhotoLibrary only as a source of ImagePicker , then it should not cause memory issue