# UIImagePickerViewController camera reload tab bar controller (viewDidLoad called)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I trying to write some app with objective-c for iOS.
I have a project with tap bar controller.
In my last tap I've button click on this I will show camera.
So when I took my photo with camera, and tap on "Use photo", it's call ViewDidLoad of parent controller of my TapBarViewController, and my tap controller reload with changeative tap

I also tried to google 
but there are no solutions..
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987855/viewdidload-is-called-every-time-after-dismiss-of-uiimagepickercontroller)and [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/113122) doesn't work for me. 
Please, what I do wrong?
My method witch call camera is:

```
      UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
      picker.delegate = self;
      picker.allowsEditing = YES;
      picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

      [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

UPDT:
Also I think that it is not resource problem like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987855/viewdidload-is-called-every-time-after-dismiss-of-uiimagepickercontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after one day of researching I found the solution.
after that I added this line it's work fine.

```
picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;
```